# Kaparos for a pregnant woman -- why the extra chicken?

Tags: minhag, women, sin, pregnancy-birth, kaparot

From [Sidur Tehilas Hashem](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32581&st=&pgnum=296&hilite=), [Sidur Rav Amram](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7284&st=&pgnum=329&hilite=), and [Nitei Gavriel Hilchos Yom Hakipurim 10:20](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46445&st=&pgnum=73&hilite=) you take additional chickens for Kaparos for a pregnant lady in order to cover the fetus. What sin (or sins) has the fetus done that it requires a Kapara?

Comment: Achila Gasa?.....

Comment: Why do you assume the child is getting a kappara? The chicken is not a korban

Comment: Some say gilgul,others say maybe mother ate something assur,and others don't include the unborn child

Comment: @doubleAA: It is called Kaparos. If it is something else please advise.

Comment: (...and that ^^^ is why the rishonim hated this.)

Comment: Is there anything about waving a chicken around your head that makes sense?

Comment: Actually, there is a huge question about pregnant women; what if she's carrying twin boys, or twin girls, or triplets...?

Comment: @user4751 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 4):

Whatever it is that would cause a fetus to die or grow sickly, whether it is the sins of the parents or a gezeira or nature roulette, which is 'hanging over the head' of this fetus, will be effected by the kaparos which will draw that away into the chicken.

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50519&st=&pgnum=241

Comment: And of course chucking the gizzards onto the roof plays a big role.

Comment: In other words, no sin -- just to shield it from possible tragedy. Am I reading you right?

Comment: @Shokhet For two of the situations. But in the third there might be sin. A parent's sin can cause a childs death if the child is very young. So if the paparent's sin has been decreed to cause this child/fetus to die, then the chicken helps for that too.