# Can the chickens swung over a pregnant woman's head for Kaparos be swung consecutively?

Tags: halacha, minhag, yom-kippur, kaparot

When swinging [3 chickens](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_29.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%94B-B%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92B%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%92) (or [2 chickens](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01043.html#HtmpReportNum0604_L2) depending on one's custom) over a pregnant woman's head for [Kaparos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapparot), must the chickens be swung simultaneously or may they be swung consecutively (so as to remain less conspicuous)?

Comment: Isn't it only two? The hen would work for the female fetus, if thats what it is, and the rooster is only neaded in case it's a male.

Comment: @user6591, [some use 3](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/adhaz/piskey/38) because they require a separate chicken per person.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does an unborn fetus not atonement? And how exactly does one gain atonement by swinging chickens around? (Surely this ceremony is supposed to invoke feelings of Teshuva. How does that relate to the fetus?)

Comment: @DannySchoemann, feel free to [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Yishai - almost did, but it's a dup of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30883/501

Comment: @DannySchoemann, I think the last question (in the parenthetical) is not actually asked there, nor is it really addressed in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Nitei Gavriel Yom Kippur 10:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46445&st=&pgnum=74&hilite=) says that it can be done consecutively.